# Can you use two SET and WHERE Statements instead of ELSE in Access SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access, jet-sql

I am trying to use two SET and WHERE Statements in place of an ELSE Statement. Is that possible? I am getting a syntax error on the following:

```
UPDATE HRBI 
SET HRBI.[MktDISC%] = 0, HRBI.[MktDISC%] = (HRBI.[MarketMedianDISCUSD] / HRBI.[FY16StartingSalaryUSD])
WHERE HRBI.[FY16StartingSalaryUSD] = 0, HRBI.[FY16StartingSalaryUSD] <> 0;
```

Comment: I hope you were able to find a solution. Remember, if the answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all your `WHERE` statement syntax is wrong, you need to use `AND` or `OR` conditional operator. Second, did you looked at `WHERE` condition; it's impossible

```
WHERE HRBI.[FY16StartingSalaryUSD] = 0, HRBI.[FY16StartingSalaryUSD] <> 0;
```

It's like saying `WHERE col1 = 0 and col1 <> 0` which is never going to be possible cause at any point in time the field can have either one of the value but not both. You can rather say `>= 0` or use a `OR` condition

```
WHERE HRBI.[FY16StartingSalaryUSD] >= 0
```

You are doing the same mistake in `SET` clause as well. Your posted query `SET` clause can simplified to

```
SET HRBI.[MktDISC%] = (HRBI.[MarketMedianDISCUSD] / HRBI.[FY16StartingSalaryUSD])
```

Comment: You just need `WHERE HRBI.[FY16StartingSalaryUSD] > 0` instead of `>=`

Comment: @dbagley, Op want `= 0 || <> 0`. To emulate that we need `>= 0`

Comment: i believe OP wanted `=0 && <>0`.  For the `=0`, OP should default the column `HRBI.[MktDISC%]` to zero and then use your solution to update the non-zero values.

Answer (score 0):

The `Switch` statement allows you to do exactly what you requested; when `FY16StartingSalaryUSD=0`, return a 0, otherwise return `MarketMedianDISCUSD/FY16StartingSalaryUSD`.

```
UPDATE HRBI 
SET HRBI.[MktDISC%] = SWITCH(
  HRBI.[FY16StartingSalaryUSD] = 0, 0, 
  HRBI.[FY16StartingSalaryUSD] <> 0, HRBI.[MktDISC%] = (HRBI.[MarketMedianDISCUSD] / HRBI.[FY16StartingSalaryUSD])
```